# String.split() is causing an empty string to be created, how do I prevent this?

Tags: java

I have a string that is a concatenation of smaller strings of the form `refNum orderNum`, as in a string that contains a reference number and the amount of items on an order e.g. `BRICK1 10`. The larger concatenated string is a number of these smaller string pieced together and using a pound sign to divide them e.g. `#BRICK1 10#BRICK2 20#BRICK3 30`.

When I use String.split() I'd like the result to be an array that has divided the larger string into its smaller elements so `BRICK1 10`, `BRICK2 20` and `BRICK3 30`, however when I actually try to split the string using "#" as a delimiter I get a fourth string at the start of the array that is empty.

I'm not sure why this is happening, how do I prevent it?

My long string is produced using this method

```
public String getAllOrders()
    {
        String orderDetails = "";

        for(BrickOrder o : orderList)
        {
            String order = "#" + o.getReferenceNumber() + " " + o.getNumberOfBricks();
            System.out.println("ORDER: " + order);
            orderDetails = orderDetails.concat(order);
        }

        return orderDetails;
    }
```

Whilst the split method is used within a test class, here.

```
@Test
    public void testFullOrderListReturnedCorrectly()
    {
        sys.createOrder(10);
        sys.createOrder(100);
        sys.createOrder(1000); //Create three orders

        String orderList = sys.getOrders(); //Return full order list
        System.out.println(orderList);

        String[] orders = orderList.split("#");
        System.out.println(orders.length);
    }
```

Comment: Yes, `sys`'s method `getOrders()` calls the `getAllOrders` method within itself. It's correct.

Answer (score 1):

You get an empty string at the start of the array because the string you are splitting starts with you chosen delimiter (`#`). You can prevent it by removing it from the beginning before splitting (using method `String.substring(int)` for example).

Example solution:

```
String[] orders = orderList.substring(1).split("#");
```

Answer (score 1):

That's what `split` does. It splits your string by using the delimiter and keeps the string, even if its empty, if it's not the last string.(trailing empty strings are excluded)
You could use a regex instead and a Pattern match. But in this case I'd recommend to just check your `orderList` before you split it and remove the `#` if it's the first character:

```
String[] orders;
if (orderList.charAt(0) == '#') {
    orders = orderList.substring(1).split("#");
} else {
    orders = orderList.split("#");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe the issue is because of the "#" that you are appending to the start of the order string.

The way split works is, it will break the order string at every "#", and the first "#" is encountered right at the beginning of the order string, and hence that is an empty.

Depending on your requirement, either you can avoid appending this "#" at the start, or you remove the "#" before spiting, or you ignore the element of the spitted array.

Hope this clarifies.

Answer (score 0):

Try this (Java 8+ is required):

```
import java.util.Arrays;
    ...
String s = "#BRICK1 10#BRICK2 20#BRICK3 30";
String[] tokens = Arrays.stream(s.split("#")).filter(t -> !t.isEmpty()).toArray(String[]::new);
```

Answer (score 0):

> how do I prevent it?

By placing delimiter between the parts you want to get with split.

Imagine, you want to split a stick in two.

How do you do it? Where would be the point of application of force?

```
Option one:  ---V---

Option two: V---V--- (looks familiar?)
```

The former gives you two sticks, obviously, and the latter would give you an empty piece of stick in the beginning. It just doesn't exist in a real world, while an empty string happen to exist in Java.

Check [String#split](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String,%20int)) documentation, it says exactly that:

> Splits this string **around** matches of the given regular expression.

Answer (score 0):

Use regex to safely (ie if any exist) remove all leading `#` chars, then split:

```
String[] ordersPairs = orderList.replaceAll("^#*", "").split("#+");
```

By splitting on `"#+"`, empty orders are also ignored/discarded.